# Why the following integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is considered hard to compute?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $\mathbb{E}[X]$ be the expected value of a continuous random variable $X$ and $p_\theta$, $q_\phi$ be two density functions parameterized by $\theta$ and $\phi$, respectively. Note that $\theta$ is not necessary equal to $\phi$.

KL-divergence is a non-symmetric non-negative measure which determines how much $p_\theta$ and $q_\phi$ differ from each other. This quantity is particularly useful when used as an addend of the Evidence Lower Bound (ELBO) formulation in auto encoders' loss function, in the context of machine learning (deep learning).

In this [video](https://youtu.be/9_eZHt2qJs4?list=PLivJwLo9VCUK1dXFU9Ig96fjANOMdoL9R&t=336) the professor shows that:

$$
\text{KL}(p_\theta\ ||\ q_\phi) = \mathbb{E}_p \bigg[log \frac{p_\theta(x)}{q_\phi(x)} \bigg] := \int_\mathbb{R} log \frac{p_\theta(x)}{q_\phi(x)}\ p_\theta(x)\ dx
$$

is hard to compute because "integral goes over $-\infty$ to $+\infty$". But I haven't fully understood why this is an issue.

He will eventually approximate that "hard" integral using a numerical method from to the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers):

$$
\int_\mathbb{R} log \frac{p_\theta(x)}{q_\phi(x)}\ p_\theta(x)\ dx \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N\ log \frac{p_\theta(x_i)}{q_\phi(x_i)}
$$

when $N$, the total number of trials, is sufficiently large.

Is the problem related to the fact that it is not possibile to get a [closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) of that integral due to the presence of "infinite sums" which may be an issue for a computer?

Comment: Does the course rely on computer-friendly numerical integration techniques such as the trapezium rule?

Comment: @J.G. The professor in that video introduces the KL divergence as a "metric" for determining how much $p_\theta$ and $q_\phi$ differ from each other. Since the "integral is hard to compute", he will approximate that integral using the law of large numbers. Then he will use KL divergence as a (component of) variational autoencoders loss function.

Comment: Yes, but the answer to question hinges on whether he tends to use numerical methods but will need a substitution so this integral is over a finite internal, or whether he would love to use analytic methods but can't but the $p_\theta,\,q_\phi$ at hand. I think the former is more likely given the comment about the $\pm\infty$ limits.